# jsp bean cannot find any information on property

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, javabeans

I can try to write a jsp with javabean . But i receive an error message from eclipse console : **Cannot find any information on property 'Uomo' in a bean of type 'conta.Contagenere'** . I think that i wrote it well, but there is something that i don't know or that i can't see!
I run all in Eclipse with server inside eclipse .

I have 3 files: form, jsp and java. And web.xml.

**Form_13_6.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Inserisci dati...</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <form action="http://127.0.0.1:8080/Esercizio_13_x/benvenuto3" method="post">
        <p>
          Nome:     <INPUT type="text"   name="nome" ><br>
          Cognome:  <INPUT type="text"   name="cognome" ><br>
          Sesso:    <INPUT type="radio"  name="sesso" value="Maschio">Maschio<INPUT type="radio" name="sesso" value="Femmina">Femmina<br>
          Età:      <INPUT type="number" name="anni" ><br>

          <input type="submit" value="Invio"> <input type="reset" value="Cancella">
        </p>
      </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Form_13_6a.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ page import="conta.Contagenere" %>

<%-- Faccio avanzare i counter --%>
<jsp:useBean id="lcontagenere" class="conta.Contagenere" scope="application"></jsp:useBean>
<% 
if(request.getParameter("sesso").compareTo("Maschio") == 0)
%>
    <jsp:setProperty property="Uomo" name="lcontagenere" value="1"/>

<%
else
%>
    <jsp:setProperty property="Donna" name="lcontagenere" value="1"/>


<%-- Creazione dinamica della pagina --%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Benvenuto...</title>
    </head>
        <body>
            <h1>
<%= 
request.getParameter("nome") + ", sei " + 
((request.getParameter("sesso").compareTo("Maschio") == 0) ? "l'uomo n." : "la donna n.")
%>

<%
if(request.getParameter("sesso").compareTo("Maschio") == 0)
%>
<jsp:getProperty property="Uomo" name="lcontagenere"/>
<%
else
%>
<jsp:getProperty property="Donna" name="lcontagenere"/>
che si registra a questa applicazione! 
<br>
Verrai rediretto su un altra pagina ...
<jsp:forward page="http://127.0.0.1:8080/Esercizio_13_x/benvenuto3b" ></jsp:forward>
            </h1>
        </body>
</html>
```

**Contagenere.java**

```
/**
 * 
 */
package conta;

/**
 * @author Gabriele
 *
 */
public class Contagenere {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private int uomo;
    /**
     * 
     */
    private int donna;
    /**
     * 
     */
    public Contagenere(){

    }
    /**
     * 
     * @return
     */
    public int getUomo(){   return uomo;    }
    /**
     * 
     * @return
     */
    public int getDonna(){  return donna;   }
    /**
     * 
     * @param i
     */
    public void setUomo(int i){ uomo+=i;    }
    /**
     * 
     * @param i
     */
    public void setDonna(int i){ donna+=i;  }
}
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">
  <display-name>Esercizio_13_x</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>


    <servlet> 
        <servlet-name>sommajsp</servlet-name> 
        <jsp-file>/Esercizio_13_1.jsp</jsp-file> 
    </servlet> 

    <servlet-mapping> 
        <servlet-name>sommajsp</servlet-name> 
        <url-pattern>/sommajsp</url-pattern> 
    </servlet-mapping>



    <servlet> 
        <servlet-name>benvenuto</servlet-name> 
        <jsp-file>/Esercizio_13_3.jsp</jsp-file> 
    </servlet> 

    <servlet-mapping> 
        <servlet-name>benvenuto</servlet-name> 
        <url-pattern>/benvenuto</url-pattern> 
    </servlet-mapping>



    <servlet> 
        <servlet-name>contaaccessihost</servlet-name> 
        <jsp-file>/Esercizio_13_4.jsp</jsp-file> 
    </servlet> 

    <servlet-mapping> 
        <servlet-name>contaaccessihost</servlet-name> 
        <url-pattern>/contaaccessihost</url-pattern> 
    </servlet-mapping>



    <servlet> 
        <servlet-name>benvenuto2</servlet-name> 
        <jsp-file>/Esercizio_13_5.jsp</jsp-file> 
    </servlet> 

    <servlet-mapping> 
        <servlet-name>benvenuto2</servlet-name> 
        <url-pattern>/benvenuto2</url-pattern> 
    </servlet-mapping>



    <servlet> 
        <servlet-name>benvenuto3</servlet-name> 
        <jsp-file>/Esercizio_13_6a.jsp</jsp-file> 
    </servlet> 

    <servlet-mapping> 
        <servlet-name>benvenuto3</servlet-name> 
        <url-pattern>/benvenuto3</url-pattern> 
    </servlet-mapping>



    <servlet> 
        <servlet-name>benvenuto3b</servlet-name> 
        <jsp-file>/Esercizio_13_6b.jsp</jsp-file> 
    </servlet> 

    <servlet-mapping> 
        <servlet-name>benvenuto3b</servlet-name> 
        <url-pattern>/benvenuto3b</url-pattern> 
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

This is my **folders** of project in eclipse:

```
D:\Dropbox\CodiciProgettiSoftware\Eclipse\workspacePSR\Esercizio_13_x>tree /f
Elenco del percorso delle cartelle per il volume Dati
Numero di serie del volume: 2831-E096
D:.
│   .classpath
│   .project
│
├───.settings
│       .jsdtscope
│       org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs
│       org.eclipse.wst.common.component
│       org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml
│       org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.ui.superType.container
│       org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.ui.superType.name
│
├───build
│   └───classes
│       └───conta
│               Contagenere.class
│
├───src
│   └───conta
│           Contagenere.java
│
└───WebContent
    │   Esercizio_13_1.jsp
    │   Esercizio_13_2.jsp
    │   Esercizio_13_3.jsp
    │   Esercizio_13_4.jsp
    │   Esercizio_13_5.jsp
    │   Esercizio_13_6a.jsp
    │   Esercizio_13_6b.jsp
    │   Form_13_1.html
    │   Form_13_3.html
    │   Form_13_5.html
    │   Form_13_6.html
    │
    ├───META-INF
    │       MANIFEST.MF
    │
    └───WEB-INF
        │   web.xml
        │
        └───lib
```

This is the **error** message from console eclipse when starts forms:

```
mar 21, 2015 11:24:14 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
AVVERTENZA: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Esercizio_13_x' did not find a matching property.
.... .... ....
mar 21, 2015 11:24:16 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
GRAVE: Servlet [benvenuto3] in web application [/Esercizio_13_x] threw load() exception
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Cannot find any information on property 'Uomo' in a bean of type 'conta.Contagenere'
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.getReadMethod(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:804)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator$GenerateVisitor.visit(Generator.java:1158)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$GetProperty.accept(Node.java:1122)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2376)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2428)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visit(Node.java:2434)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Root.accept(Node.java:464)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2376)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator.generate(Generator.java:3594)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:250)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:356)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:336)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:323)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:570)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:356)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.init(JspServlet.java:138)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1144)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1031)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4909)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5196)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

mar 21, 2015 11:24:16 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFORMAZIONI: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
mar 21, 2015 11:24:16 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFORMAZIONI: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
mar 21, 2015 11:24:16 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFORMAZIONI: Server startup in 1510 ms
```

Thank you in advance anyone who helps me.

Comment: I think this is because you are capitalising first character of property.

Comment: you suggest is OK! thanks a lot! I don't see it! thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your problem after changing html elements it is working fine. 
**First of all to map jsp beans both html elements name and bean class property to which we want to map SHOULD BE SAME.**
 **In JSP page I renamed your fields to **uomo & donna**. both should be same to mapping bean component**

 In your JSP page also I renamed sesso to uomo and added {} for if else blocks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Inserisci dati...</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form action="Esercizio_13_6a.jsp" method="post">
    <p>
      Nome:     <INPUT type="text"   name="nome" ><br>
      Cognome:  <INPUT type="number"   name="cognome" ><br>
      Sesso:    <INPUT type="radio"  name="uomo" value="Maschio">Maschio<INPUT type="radio" name="sesso" value="Femmina">Femmina<br>
      Età:      <INPUT type="number" name="donna" ><br>

      <input type="submit" value="Invio"> <input type="reset" value="Cancella">
    </p>
  </form>
</body>
```

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ page import="conta.Contagenere" %>

<%-- Faccio avanzare i counter --%>
<jsp:useBean id="lcontagenere" class="conta.Contagenere" scope="application"></jsp:useBean>
<% 
if(request.getParameter("uomo").compareTo("Maschio") == 0)
{
%>
    <jsp:setProperty property="uomo" name="lcontagenere" value="1"/>

<%}
else{
%>
    <jsp:setProperty property="donna" name="lcontagenere" value="1"/>

<% }%>
<%-- Creazione dinamica della pagina --%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Benvenuto...</title>
    </head>
        <body>
            <h1>
<%= 
request.getParameter("nome") + ", sei " + 
((request.getParameter("uomo").compareTo("Maschio") == 0) ? "l'uomo n." : "la donna n.")
%>

<%
if(request.getParameter("uomo").compareTo("Maschio") == 0)
{ %>
<jsp:getProperty property="uomo" name="lcontagenere"/>
<% }
else
{ %>
<jsp:getProperty property="donna" name="lcontagenere"/>
<% } %>
che si registra a questa applicazione! 
<br>
Verrai rediretto su un altra pagina ...

            </h1>
        </body>
</html>
```